# Does someone sell latex-free jump stretch/exercise looped bands?

Tags: exercise-equipment

I have searched extensively for all sorts of different name combinations for latex-free jump stretch/exercise bands. I see that there are Theraband-style light bands that are latex-free, but all of the more heavy-duty bands for stretching seem to be rubber latex. Is there some better name for these bands I should be using to search for them? Does someone sell latex-free ones?

Here is an example of a latex one:
[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/SeriousSteel-Single-Pull-Up-CrossFit-Power-Lifting/dp/B0064DPLMY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064DPLMY)

Comment: Interesting that there appears to be so little latex-free under the bands.  I did find some tubes using "latex-free resistance tubing" but they aren't the "loop bands" as pictured.

Comment: What are you looking to use the bands for?-

Comment: @brentlance movements like making easier to stretch my hamstrings with my leg straight, also for applying loading while stretching and mobilizing areas.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy Thanks for looking. I am interested in the lack of anything for sale too!

Comment: Maybe this, where the bands don't touch the skin? http://www.amazon.com/Kbands-Resistance-Official-KbandsTraining-com-weight/dp/B00AEST19Y/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397151937&sr=8-1&keywords=kbands

Comment: Thank you Ryan for asking this question i too am allergic to latex and have been searching everywhere for loopband to assist me in pullup for crossfit. Please let me know if you find anything. Diane Castro

Comment: I am a Pilates instructor and also find this very frustrating that none if the major companies specializing in exercise bands such as Theraband or Cando will manufacture their loops in no latex material. One company told me they could possibly special order but it would require a minimum order of 1000 units ughhh! This would be an incredible market to capture for an interested company as so many of us work with latex sensitive clients. Theraband has most recently released a new product called called "Theraband CLX Consecutive Loops" that comes in non latex and latex. It can be bought in 5 ft l

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [RubberBanditz Power Resistance Bands](http://rubberbanditz.com/product/all-products/power-resistance-band/).  According to their site:

> NOTE: Colors may vary. All circular exercise bands are 41in (104 cm) in length and come in three sizes with varying resistances. **Our natural rubber latex is over 99.998% free of soluble proteins (latex allergens).** Effects of use by people with latex sensitivity is unknown and not recommended.

You'll also find them under the name "Power Bands" or "Strength Bands", and they are used often enough in power lifting.  You are correct though, latex seems to provide more robust bands for heavy duty work.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm interested in latex-free because of latex sensitivity. One of the people who would be using the bands has latex contact dermatitis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think they are going to be out of luck for the power bands.  Every last brand that I've seen are latex based--probably due to the superior support that particular type of rubber has for the purpose.  Other types of rubber will not be strong enough or have enough stretch.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answers the question, but perhaps these elastic ropes can be effective analog for stretching and assistend pull-ups.

[image]

I imagine that buying bunch of them would allow to combine from least assist (one rope) to heavy assist (10 ropes) easily and latex-free.

[Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZH6L15)